# Get MySQL image size stored in blob

Tags: c++, mysql, size, blob, mysql-connector

I have to read some images stored in a blob field using MySQL Connector/C++. The following code works great

```
std::istream *blobIn;
char buffer[6750];
memset(buffer, '\0', 6750);
blobIn = res->getBlob("att");
blobIn->read((char*)buffer,6750);       
std::ofstream outfile ("foto.jpeg",std::ofstream::binary);
outfile.write (buffer,6750);
outfile.close();
```

I'm aware that images cannot have a size greater than 6750, but I would like to know the current byte size and do something like this:

```
std::istream *blobIn;
char* buffer;
int size = getByteSizeFromBlob();
buffer = new char[size];
blobIn = res->getBlob("att");
blobIn->read((char*)buffer,size); 
....
delete buffer;
```

Some people on the internet suggest using this function

```
SELECT OCTET_LENGTH('att') FROM table
```

or

```
SELECT LENGTH('att') FROM table
```

The problem is that this query is always returning 3 as a result, while blob is returning, e.g., 6110 bytes. With MySQL Workbench, if I choose "Open value in editor" I can see the correct byte size, so how can I retrieve the corresponding size in C++??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax should be;

```
SELECT OCTET_LENGTH(att) FROM table
```

What you're selecting in your version with the field name single quoted is the byte length of the string "att" which is obviously always 3 :)